# Why does malloc(500000000) return NULL when I have 8GB available memory?

Tags: c, memory, crash, malloc

I've been experimenting around recently in C, just trying to learn whats happening on the hardware and what the compilers doing under the hood. My code has been crashing when I allocate a large amount and I wasn't sure why. I wrote a test snippet to see how small I could make this happen. The snippet looks like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int n = 400000000;
    int* x = malloc(sizeof(int)*n);
    
    if (x == NULL)
    {
        printf("isnull\n");
        system("PAUSE");
        return 0;
    }
        
    x[0] = 1;
    
    for(int i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        x[i] = x[i - 1] + 1;
    }
    printf("%i\n", x[n - 1]);
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

I've noticed a few things:

Firstly this size seems to be close to the limit. 400 million elements wont crash the program but 500 million will.

I don't believe I'm hitting the integer overflow limit but if I change n to be unsigned the program behaves the same.

I have ample system resources, 500 million integers should only take 2GB whereas I have close to 8GB available.

I'm still not sure why this is happening but if anyone can share insight into this I would appreciate it. I've been running this on Windows 10, MinGW GCC 9.2.0

Comment: it looks like it is null, what might be causing this when changing only the malloc size?

Comment: The heap limit on Windows is somewhere around 2GB. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1342715/max-heap-usage-allowed-per-process

Comment: Are you compiling a 32 bit or a 64 bit program?

Comment: Now that you point that out I realise that I am using mingw32. Could that contribute?

Comment: Ok so, after reading through the link Lundin provided (which broadened my understanding a lot) and the revelation that im compiling in the 32 bit version I think that makes sense now. The program is limited to ~4GB but only a certain amount of that is heap memory limiting it further.

Comment: @MattyHooper I don't use mingw32, but you can check if the .exe file generated by the compiler is a 32 or a 64 bit program: Check out this: https://superuser.com/questions/358434/how-to-check-if-a-binary-is-32-or-64-bit-on-windows. On Windows, 32 bit programs cannot allocate more than 2GB (or in certain cases 3GB) of memory.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Thats a pretty interesting method, yeah it was a 32 bit binary

Comment: @MattyHooper that explains it...

Comment: There's mingw64 which is more recently maintained than mingw32, which I don't think is maintained since forever.

Comment: Is this a 32-bit program? They operate in a memory space of 4 GiB, of which they can only actually use as little as 2 GiB.

Answer (score 1):

1. Always check the result of `malloc` as it may fail (and you will dereference the NULL pointer).
2. Operating system may terminate the program when a process is consuming too much memory. The operating system intervenes to terminate the program which potentially can destabilize the host (Linux exit code 137).

https://godbolt.org/z/96n9sbaMc

If you need to use memory in Linux try to increase the size of the swap file (even temporarily `swapon`), check and set the system limits (`ulimit`)

Answer (score -1):

Heap memory is part of your ram. You don't get the full 8GB of heap. There's space put aside for stack, variables, global stuff and heap that you gotta keep in mind.